# Parse url or ip adress and count word length before each occurrence in c?

Tags: c, url, dns, ip

Need to parse a url or ip by its delimiter '.' and count the word length before each delimiter in C. In other words www.google.com would return 
www -3 
google -6 
com -3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at *strtok* and *strlen* in string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char url[] = "www.google.com";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(url, ".");
    while(token != NULL) {
        printf("%s -%d\n", token, (int)strlen(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's better to give example for OP .

Comment: I tried that not quite sure how strtok works. Would you be able to provide an example.

Comment: @Fact http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html

Comment: Added an example, not sure how I could have lead you to the answer, but here's an example of how to use strtok, you can also look it up by  doing `man 3 strtok`